# Which number translation is correct?

Tags: grammar

I need to write a numeral in 汉字。

But I am not sure, if I need to put 一 in huge numerals before tens.
So, my numeral is 81,016 and my question is: do I need to write:

八万一千零一十六

or:

八万一千零十六

Which form is right? Thank you for helping!

Comment: Chinese a Comprehensive Grammar:note that in counting numbers larger than 100, 一 yi 'one' has to be incorporated before tens as well, thus 八万一千零一十六 is needed

Comment: Might as well put it as 八万一千十六, because there is no confusion here.

Comment: @倪阔乐 no, in this case, 零 is a must, unless there's some hundred(s).

Comment: @Stan: No, it is optional if there is no ambiguity.

Comment: @倪阔乐 it seems currently there's no authoritative standard for that. But 八万一千十六 really sounds awkward to my ears, I don't know how other native speakers feel. :/

Comment: @Stan @倪阔乐 for 81016, `八万一千零一十六` is the most natural one. `八万一千零十六` and `八万一千一十六` are acceptable. and i would say `八万一千十六` is awkward. i am from hong kong.

Comment: 零 here is a must, while 一 is optional

Answer (score 4):

Both representations (`八万一千零一十六` and `八万一千零十六`) are correct, while `八万一千零一十六` sounds more natural.

---

### Rule

The rule is actually very simple.

> Use `十…` instead of `一十…` at the very beginning of the number. Otherwise, just keep the `一十`.

Example:

> 1 = 一
>   11 = `十`一
>   310 = 三百`一十`
>   3010 = 三千零`一十`
>   3310 = 三千三百`一十`
>   30010 = 三万零`一十`
>   100010 = `十`万零`一十`
>   30100010 = 三千零`一十`万零`一十`

---

### Tools

You can use online tools to do the conversion. **Input Arabic numbers, and get Chinese output.** Both tools can handle negative value & decimal places. It is suggested to compare the result from both tools if using for formal usage.

1. [**Mandatintools.com**](http://www.mandarintools.com/numbers.html) - Variety of output styles:

   - Traditional Chinese - `81016 = 八萬一千零一十六`
   - Simplified Chinese - `81016 = 八万一千零一十六`
   - Traditional Chinese (formal) - `81016 = 捌萬壹仟零壹拾陸`
   - Simplified Chinese (formal) - `81016 = 捌万壹仟零壹拾陆`
   - Pinyin - `81016 = ba1 wan4 yi1 qian1 ling2 yi1 shi2 liu4`

> All translations are perfectly correct and natural, except:
>
> - The character `一` is not necessary for those beginning with `一十...` (e.g. `一十二萬零五`, `一十億`). It is still correct, but unnatural.

---

2. [**Chinesetools.eu**](http://www.chinesetools.eu/tools/chinesenumbers/) - Variety of input types (Numbers, Dates, Years, Time, Money, Fractions, Decimals, Percents). Only one output style:

   - Simplified Chinese with Pinyin
     `120101 = 十二万〇一百〇一 shíèr wàn/mò líng yībǎi líng yī`

> All translations are perfectly correct and natural, except:
>
> - I cannot understand why `万` has a pinyin of `mò`.
> - The dollar character should be `块` instead of `快`.

Comment: How well can we trust that online tool?

Comment: i have tested quite several numbers. all the translated chinese number are perfectly fine, except  the character `一` is not necessary in cases like `100000 = 一十萬`, `1000000000 = 一十億`, `10000000000000 = 一十兆`. for example, `120555 = 一十二萬零五百五十五` is more natural to be writtern as `十二萬零五百五十五`. alternatively, you can try [**this tool**](http://www.chinesetools.eu/tools/chinesenumbers/) although only simplified chinese translation is provided. i didn't find any translation issues in this tool.

Comment: let me add it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

八万一千零一十六 is the correct way to say it.
八万一千零十六 would be understood, but sounds awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I think "八万一千零一十六" is more common and formal, though "八万一千零十六" can be used also.

Comment: Hi j5shi, thank you for your contribution! It would be better if you add more information with reference :D

Comment: You may find it (written in Chinese) here: http://baike.baidu.com/view/1624026.htm, the reason why 十六 should be written in 一十六 was originated from the bank, to avoid the notes from being changed maliciously, e.g. 十六 may be changed to 二十六